# Voltage divider in op amp

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, voltage-divider

I don’t understand how they calculated V+. I would appreciate an explanation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Many ways to solve it. Voltage divider, superposition, KCL.

Comment: It doesn't affect the V+ calculation,  but are you sure that circuit is drawn correctly? It won't work as an amplifier as-drawn ...

Comment: The circuit is correct.  It is not a non-inverting amplifier.

Comment: @AnalogKid Are you sure? It works as an amplifier?

Comment: @LvW that would work as an *inverting* amplifier if the opamp inputs were reversed. As-drawn, it's a comarator (of sorts) with some hysteresis. The output of this circuit will be one rail or the other (or as close as the opamp can get), with no in-between state.

Comment: LvW - not as a *linear* amplifier.  R1 and R2 set the hysteresis window - the voltage difference between the positive-going and negative-going transition levels.

Comment: @AnalogKid Do you think that this circuit can even be called a (non-linear) amplifier? This was the background of my former comment.

Comment: Technically, maybe, but I've never seen it.  You could say it is a circuit with a non-linear function, as an introduction to the workings of a comparator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Maybe you are confused by the presence of the op-amp. Try considering this: -

[image]

Current \$I\$ is common to both resistors so, just use what you know from ohm's law to construct an equation to find the voltage at \$V+\$. Here's a little start for you: -

$$I = \dfrac{V_{OUT}-V_{IN}}{R_1+R_2}$$

Comment: Got it! A follow up question, why did you assume that current flows from Vout to Vin and not vice versa?

Comment: @RaheeqDarawsha I could have assumed the current ran the other way and I would still end up with the right answer because the voltages across the resistors would reverse. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: @Raheeq Darawsha The problem with the circuit (and the calculation) will be that Vin is a sinusoidal voltage (as it seems) whereas the voltage Vout will be a DC value (because the circuit will not linearly amplify and the output will be saturuated)

Comment: @LvW why are you suggesting to the OP that there is a problem? Are you suggesting that there's a problem with my answer? Clearly it's not a straightforward amplifier because of the positive feedback (as you mentioned in your comment under the question) but, what's the problem that you see here?

Comment: @Andy oh no - there is no problem with your answer. My comment was directed to the questioner only and it was my intention to point to the fact that the difference (Vout-Vin) is not very meanigful when Vout is a saturation voltage and Vin is a small ac signal. What do you expect as a result?

Comment: @LvW My only intention is to analyse the question, figure out if it's valid and make an answer if I know it.

Comment: @Andy aka Yes - and your answer was, of course, correct.  However, in some cases the question may arise: Does the answer reveal some interesting/important information which may help to better understand the purpose and the function of a specific circuit? This was the only background of my comment - nothing else.